# Replace outer wrapping brackets with a prefix

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string that could look like this

`More text here ID[20] [Choice 5] More text here`

I need to convert it to this

`More text here 20 [Choice 5] More text here`

Essentially I need to remove any outer wrapping `ID[num]` and preserve the number inside.

I did this:

`string.replace(/ID\[/g, ' ')`

And that removes the `ID[` at the start, but I can't figure out how to remove the trailing `]`

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
s = s.replace(/ID\[(\d+)]/g, '$1')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xCytOn/1)

**Details**

- `ID\[` - a literal string `ID[`
- `(\d+)` - Group 1: one or more digits
- `]` - a literal `]`

The `$1` is a backreference to the Group 1 value. That is, it will remove all but the digits inside the `ID[...]`.

To match `ID` as a whole word, add `\b` before `ID` (to avoid replacing similar matches, as in `CREATIONID[5]`).

JS demo:

```js
var s = "More text here ID[20] [Choice 5] More text here";
s = s.replace(/ID\[(\d+)]/g, "$1");
console.log(s);
```